# What happens when an LCD screen turns black/shuts off?

Tags: lcd

I read about how an LCD screen works [here](https://www.explainthatstuff.com/lcdtv.html), and it made me wonder what actually happens when the screen shuts off. Based off of this, I can think of several possibilities:

1. Electricity is supplied to all the pixels/crystals, thus making them all appear dark. While this fits with the on/off explanations given in that article, it seems like a significant waste of energy to use extra energy when *not* in use.
2. Electricity is *not* supplied to all the pixels, which would light them all up, but the backlight shuts off, so the screen appears dark.
3. Electricity is maintained to the pixels that were receiving electricity when the screen was on, but the backlight shuts off so the screen appears dark.

I would be curious to know if different phases of the off screen are different (such as a off-screen-like screen saver versus a sleep mode or being shut off, etc.).

Comment: You can usually see the difference between #1 and #2. There's always a bit of light still visible in case #1 (which sometimes happens with screensavers, though less nowadays than was the case a few years back). If the screen is really off, you would be in case #2.

Comment: Crossposted to https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29510/what-happens-when-an-lcd-screen-shuts-off Please don't post the same question to multiple sites.

Comment: Most of the power consumption is from the backlight so for power savings you would want to shut down or dim the backlight. Most backlights are designed to create constant light over the entire display, so it cannot be turned off selectively, though there is no reason why that could not be done (for example to maintain a time display or small annunciator panel with most of the display off).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Selectively turning off the backlight is used in some LED TV panels, I think, to achieve a higher dynamic range. I'm not sure how popular it is, though.

Answer (score 1):

First the backlight is turned off to mask what happens next. Then either the crystals are driven in idle state if possible to gracefully shut it down and then the screen refresh is stopped. Otherwise the screen just fades away when refresh stops. It depends on whether you actually push the standby button so the device shuts nicely or if you just pull the plug. Anyway, it should not consume power during standby.